# How to transfer data from OneDrive to Azure SQL Server?

Tags: azure-data-factory, onedrive

I have a client who has a `.txt` file to store data from an application into OneDrive. He need to have this data synchronized into Azure SQL database once every week.

I tried to use Azure Data Factory and add a trigger to do so, but there is no such connector to OneDrive.

Is there a workaround to transfer files from OneDrive to an Azure SQL database?

Comment: Are you able to get that data into a Blob Storage first? If so, getting that data from there will be a lot easier. It probably goes without saying that it might be wise to advise the client against this workflow for a plethora of reasons. Maybe something like this could do the trick: https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-US/templates/details/2f90b5d3-029b-4e2e-ad37-1c0fe6d187fe/when-a-file-is-uploaded-to-onedrive-copy-it-to-azure-storage-container/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no out of box ADF connector to copy files directly from OneDrive.
But as an alternative you can use Power Automate to copy data from one drive.

[image]

So you can leverage power automate with one drive as source and Azure SQL database as sink

Answer (score 0):

> Since there is no inbuilt connector for OneDrive in ADF, You can consider using logic App or writing your own code using OneDrive SDK, that can perform copy of data from OneDrive.